# Use bloc provider into existing flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, bloc, flutter-bloc

im having a flutter + dart application which is working fine, but for state management we need to make use of the bloc provider. i dont have any clue about the implementation, even though all the examples where about the default counter application, mine is enterprise application. so is there any way or any solutions in how to implement bloc to my existing flutter application.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-bloc-for-beginners-839e22adb9f5 Maybe this will help. It’s hard to give you advice with so little information about your app/code

Answer (score 0):

what could be better of official [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted) with Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can refer Bloc official [documentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) which is really helpful for you. After that create one small demo and understand how it's works? In enterprise level you can use Bloc with module wise or functionality wise. Bloc is very useful library and make your work very easy..

You can also follow YouTube tutorial for your references.